# What does "so far" in the following sentences mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "Advances in medical care mean living to 100 has become a very real possibility for many. But you can only make your nest egg stretch so far."

What does "*so far*" mean?

Comment: The idiom is ***only** ... so far*. Your nest egg will stretch *so far = up to a certain point*, but no further.

Comment: The 'only' is not required though,  this makes perfect sense and transmits the same message

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey: Without ***only*** I'd be assuming the writer meant you ***can** stretch your money **that** far* (i.e. - far enough that it ***will*** last into your second century), which is pretty much the precise opposite of what it means here.

Answer (score 1):

As Fumblefingers writes, it means '*to a specific point*'.

> ***so far phrase 1*** To a certain limited extent.
>
> The commitment to free trade goes ***only so far***
>
> Aid will go ***only so far***; trade must do the rest.’
>
> You can stretch the elastic ***so far*** but you will get to the point where it snaps.’
>
> In Egypt's classrooms, lessons go ***only so far***. Parents spend $2.4 billion annually to illegally hire private teachers.’

([Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/so_far))

Comment: Hello, Laetitia. It's better to direct questions lacking signs of basic research towards the requirement on ELU for some.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ok, I did not know that. I'll keep that in mind.